# How do I install a triple boot Archlinux / Windows 11 / Kali Linux?

Tags: multi-boot, windows-11, grub, arch-linux, kali-linux

I'd like to ask for your help with a "special" installation. I'm looking to install Archlinux, Windows 11 and Kali Linux on the same SSD. I've succeeded in the first two installations, but I can't manage the last one.

Here is my partition table:

```sh
❯ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1      259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk  
|-nvme0n1p1  259:1    0   1.5G  0 part  /efi
|-nvme0n1p2  259:2    0   200G  0 part  
| `-cryptdev 254:0    0   200G  0 crypt /var/log
|                                       /var/tmp
|                                       /var/cache
|                                       /var/lib/libvirt
|                                       /home
|                                       /.snapshots
|                                       /
|-nvme0n1p3  259:3    0    10G  0 part  
|-nvme0n1p4  259:4    0    16M  0 part  
|-nvme0n1p5  259:5    0   200G  0 part  
|-nvme0n1p6  259:6    0   785M  0 part  
`-nvme0n1p7  259:7    0  64.7G  0 part
```

- `nvme0n1p1` is the EFI partition, it also contains the grub (I don't have a boot partition)
- `nvme0n1p2` is the Archlinux system (in BTRFS encrypted)
- `nvme0n1p3` is an unencrypted exchange partition (which should be able to be mounted on all three systems)
- `nvme0n1p4`, `nvme0n1p5` and `nvme0n1p6` are the three partitions required for Windows 11
- `nvme0n1p7` is left over from my attempt to install Kali Linux

Please note that archlinux uses zram for swap.
GRUB also has os-prober enabled.

Ideally, I'd like to install Kali Linux on the disk space corresponding to the seventh partition and have the system encrypted. I don't want a swap partition.

I tried several methods:

- Use the assisted partitioning tool, which unfortunately considers that it will not be able to run correctly (given the size of the partition).
- Install manually in encrypted volume, but then I had other problems: the installer failed to detect GRUB on the EFI partition, so I decided to continue anyway. I went back to my Archlinux and used os-prober but without success. I then mounted the encrypted partition (still from Archlinux) and GRUB detected and added an entry for Kali Linux. But immediately after entering the decryption password, I get several errors telling me that I need to load the kernel first, that the partition is not found, etc. (although the ID specified by GRUB is the correct one). So I tried one last time to see what I could do in chroot from Archlinux and unfortunately not much.

Can you help me cleanly install Kali Linux in triple boot and make it detectable and bootable via GRUB?

**UPDATE**

I managed to install all three OSes using `nvme0n1p7` as root for Kali and `nvme0n1p1` as the EFI partition. The installation went well but when I rebooted the computer displayed a "Kali linux" GRUB and not my basic GRUB. So I changed in my UEFI to get my Archlinux GRUB, then I regenerated the configuration and now all partitions are detected.

The only problem is that it only works if the Kali root partition is not encrypted.

I'd also like to point out that I want all three OSes for the following reasons:

- Archlinux: It's my daily OS, I'm used to it.
- Windows: For system programming, it's more practical than a VM.
- Kali Linux: For pentest tools, I know they're available on Archlinux, but unfortunately I have too many problems installing them.

Comment: Why bother? Any software which runs on Kali is available for Arch. Installing Kali is such a waste of effort.

Comment: I don’t know why a smart solution would be downvoted.   Triple booting is a terrible way to run a computer

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier to run Kali in a container/chroot – lets you use Kali tools while booted into Arch. (And the knowledge about installing a Linux distro into a chroot can be transferred to installing the distro onto a partition.)

Comment: That is very close to what I posted about using Virtual Machines.